# Replace words in txt by powersell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a txt file contain all path to folder in each line.

```
K:\AppData\Released_To_Production\EDCO\1632
K:\AppData\Released_To_Production\EDCO\1633
K:\AppData\Released_To_Production\EDCO\1634
```

I am using poweshell to replace `K:\` with `D:\data\` so it should like this

```
D:\Data\AppData\Released_To_Production\EDCO\1632
D:\Data\AppData\Released_To_Production\EDCO\1633
D:\Data\AppData\Released_To_Production\EDCO\1634
```

It should be very simple but I cant get it through.....

```
Get-Content C:\work\path.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "K':''\'", "D':''\'Data" } | Set-Content C:\work\000.txt
```

there is nothing replaced in output file......

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:

```
${C:\work\path.txt} -replace 'K:\\','D:\Data\' | Set-Content C:\work\000.txt
```

Here's another twist :-)

```
${C:\work\000.txt} = ${C:\work\path.txt} -replace 'K:\\','D:\Data\'
```

Comment: It's not correct that this is only answer that works. The Replace-FileString.ps1 script works also; I just tested and verified.

Comment: I tried this ${C:\work\path.txt} and can see that it works to return the contents of the file. But I don't understand *why* it works. My understanding of the ${...} syntax was that it was for creating variable names with non-standard characters in them. Why does it read the contents of a file? In any case, thanks for teaching me something new today!

Comment: Each drive can be accessed using variable syntax.  You've probably done it and not realized it e.g. `$env:path` or `$function:prompt`. C is a PSDrive just like Env and Function. In the case of the files, you have to use `${}` syntax to read the file's contents e.g. `${c:foo.txt}` which only works if foo.txt is in the current directory.  Or you can specify the full path `${c:\work\path.txt}`.

Comment: BTW I love this little example of what you can do with this syntax `${c:f1.txt},${c:f2.txt} = ${c:f2.txt},${c:f1.txt}`.  Fairly succinct syntax to swap file contents.  This also shows that, as with any variable, you can assign the file's contents as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the ForEach-Object. You can replace it in one step:

```
(Get-Content C:\work\path.txt) -replace "K:\\", "D:\Data" | Set-Content C:\work\000.txt
```

Note that the first parameter of -replace is a regular expression, so you need to escape the backslash.

Comment: That won't work because Get-Content will interpret `-replace` as a parameter and it doesn't have a Replace parameter.  Try putting parens around `Get-Content C:\work\path.txt`.

Comment: Doh! You're right. I had it correct in my console, but missed the parens when transcribing it here. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content C:\work\path.txt  | % { $_.replace("K:\","D:\data\")} | Set-Content C:\work\000.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Replace-FileString.ps1 script from this article:

[Windows IT Pro: Replacing Strings in Files Using PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/replacing-strings-files-using-powershell)

```
Replace-FileString -path C:\work\path.txt -pattern '^K:\\' -replacement 'D:\Data\' -Multiline
```

The **-Multiline** parameter tells the script that ^ should match the beginnings of lines (rather than the beginning of the file). To overwrite the file with a copy containing the replaced strings, add the **-Overwrite** parameter.